# How can i check an ethereum transaction signature in an existing block

Tags: signature

Let’s suppose a past ethereum transaction.

This is a basic transaction: send ether between 2 Wallets. There are no smartcontract.

This transaction has been include in a block.

I want to check the signature of this transaction ?

How can i do this ? It seems signatures are not stored on the blockchain. Where are they ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the validators, nodes, and the Ethereum network check the transaction signatures for you before the transaction is included in the block and the signatures are not stored on the blockchain regardless whether the transaction is between EOA or smart contracts, or EOA and smart contract.

See:

[Why ethereum dons't store transaction signature?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62388/why-ethereum-donst-store-transaction-signature)

Comment: Thanks but signatures may be present in mempool ? How can i see them ?

Comment: See: https://www.quicknode.com/guides/web3-sdks/how-to-access-ethereum-mempool

Comment: Yes but i do not see signatures in mempool…